# Remove double quote from an array

Tags: php, laravel

I am using `WhereIn()` method in Laravel to fetch various 'id', but the problem is the data am getting is like this `["6,19"]` what am i expecting is an array with numbers without double quotes.

The data am getting is from a varchar field so, it comes as varchar and now i need to change that as [6,19] without double quotes. Please guide me to do so.

The `whereIn` method supports only array with numbers.

```
public function getusers($id)
{
    $users = User::where('member_id', $id)->get();

    foreach($users as $user)
    {
        $s = $user->path;

        $s = str_replace('/', ',', $s); //this gives 6,19 and if i wrap that with [] it gives us ["6,19"].

        return $usergs = User::whereIn("id", [$s])->get(); //[$s] gives like ["6,19"] -but i need to change that as [6,19] (array not string)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explode on `/` instead, which makes it an array. You can then pass that array into `whereIn()` without needing to replace anything.

```php
public function getusers($id)
{
    $users = User::where('member_id', $id)->get();

    foreach($users as $user) {
        $s = explode("/", $user->path);

        return $usergs = User::whereIn("id", $s)->get();
    }

}
```